# How to create an "order" object at the same time as user

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on an application to order food without forcing the user to log in. He can order by providing information just during the order.
when I try to create a command I want to create my user at the same time.
My issue is that when creating the order an error message is displayed and I don't know what to do to solve this problem.
**Model - Order**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./User')
const Meal = require('./Meal')
const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    customer: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: User,
      required: true
    },
    orderedmeal: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: Meal,
      required: true
    },
    ordertotal: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
      default:0
    },
    dateOrder: String,
    status: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema);
```

**Controller - create Order**

```
exports.createOrder = async (req, res) => {

  const newOrder = new Order(req.body)
  newOrder.save();

  return res.status(200).json({
    customer: newOrder.customer, 
    orderedmeal: newOrder.orderedmeal,
    ordertotal: newOrder.ordertotal,
    dateOrder: newOrder.dateOrder,
    status : newOrder.status
  })
}
```

**Orderform**

```
const [order, setOrder] = useState();
  
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      try {
        const res = await axios.post(GET_ORDERS_URL, {
          customer: {
            firstname: firstname,
            lastname: lastname,
            numTel: numTel,
            address: address,
          },
          orderedmeal: orderedmeal,
          ordertotal: orderTotal,
          dateOrder: dateOrder,
        });

        setOrder(res.data);
        console.log("Order ", order);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
  };
```

**Résults on Console**

```
    this.$__.validationError = new ValidationError(this);
                                ^

 ValidationError: Order validation failed: customer: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{
   firstname: 'djamila',
   lastname: 'azouane',
   numTel: '0777776602',
   address: 'Hussein Dey'
 }" (type Object) at path "customer" because of "BSONTypeError"
     at model.Document.invalidate (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:3054:32)
     at model.$set (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1409:12)
     at model.$set (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1092:16)
     at model.Document (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:166:12)
     at model.Model (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:119:12)
     at new model (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4999:15)
     at exports.createOrder (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\Controllers\order.js:9:20)
     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
     at next (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
     at next (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:138:14) {
   errors: {
     customer: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{
       firstname: 'djamila',
       lastname: 'azouane',
       numTel: '0777776602',
       address: 'Hussein Dey'
     }" (type Object) at path "customer" because of "BSONTypeError"
         at ObjectId.cast (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:248:11)
         at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1201:12)    
         at model.$set (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1367:22)
         at model.$set (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1092:16)
         at model.Document (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:166:12)
         at model.Model (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:119:12)
         at new model (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4999:15)
         at exports.createOrder (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\Controllers\order.js:9:20)
         at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)      
         at next (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13) {
       stringValue: '"{\n' +
         "  firstname: 'djamila',\n" +
         "  lastname: 'azouane',\n" +
         "  numTel: '0777776602',\n" +
         "  address: 'Hussein Dey'\n" +
         '}"',
       messageFormat: undefined,
       kind: 'ObjectId',
       value: {
         firstname: 'djamila',
         lastname: 'azouane',
         numTel: '0777776602',
         address: 'Hussein Dey'
       },
       path: 'customer',
       reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
           at new BSONTypeError (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\bson\lib\error.js:41:28)
           at new ObjectId (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\bson\lib\objectid.js:67:23)
           at castObjectId (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:25:12)
           at ObjectId.cast (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:246:12)
           at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1201:12)  
           at model.$set (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1367:22)
           at model.$set (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1092:16)
           at model.Document (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:166:12)
           at model.Model (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:119:12)
           at new model (C:\Users\hp\Documents\booking\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4999:15),
       valueType: 'Object'
     }
   },
   _message: 'Order validation failed'
 }
 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**Frontend + Navigation Console**
[image: Frontend + Console navigation]

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your order schema, `customer` has type "ObjectId", and when you pass req to create order, you pass customer object, which is causing the error.
In your `createOrder` function, first, you need to save the customer object and then use its id to create an order.